# How to do keyword query in MySQL with big data amount?

Tags: mysql

Here is the scenario:

I want to do a keyword query in `MySQL` with **big data amount**, which is in **10 million** level.

The match is just **to judge whether the keyword is a substring of the current specified field.**

If there is a string: "A BC DEF", and the keyword is "BC", then it is matched. Just this simple, but I want it to be as quickly as possible. Because this is gonna applied to a website's search module （**with relatively high concurrency**）, I don't want the user to wait for a long time.

Could anyone give me an idea? Thanks a lot!

**P.S.** I've searched things about `fulltext` in MySQL, as well as some search engines like `Lucene` and `Sphinx`, which one is better and more appropriate to apply? My web project is based on Java EE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using MySQL Full-Text Search Functions

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Then you can use a SQL Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('BC');
```

Comment: If my table size is about 4G, how much space would `fulltext index` gonna take? Anyway, I'll go through the manual first:)